# TikZ - forest - for nodewalk to add a root-to-leaf path

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

In the following M(erly)WE, here is my goal.

1. I would like to give the colors as an argument.
2. I would like to decorate all the edges and nodes from the root to the leaf marked.

Here is the output of the code below.

[image]

I am trying to use `for nodewalk` but I don't see how to...

- ... define the node as an argument or using a style,
- ... define the color as an argument,
- ... put a frame around each nodes,
- ... have the good left points for the colored edges.

Here is the partial code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\section{Mark all nodes}

\begin{forest}
  for tree = {
    grow'  = 0,
    l      = 2.5cm,
    parent anchor=east,
    s sep  = 1.2cm,
  },
  mark/.style = {
    mark node,edge=mark line
  },
  mark node/.style = {
    draw = red,
    line width = 2pt,
    rounded corners
  },
  /tikz/mark line/.style={
    red,
    line width = 2.5pt,
    line cap = round,
    shorten >= -1pt, % this (TikZ) key deals with "links" between edges and nodes
  },
  [
    [A, mark=red
      [B]
      [C,mark=blue]
    ]
    [D, mark=red
      [E, mark=red
        [F]
        [G, mark=red]
        [H]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}


\section{Try to indicate only the leaf}

\begin{forest}
  for tree = {
    grow'  = 0,
    l      = 2.5cm,
    parent anchor=east,
    s sep  = 1.2cm,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for nodewalk={
      c,
      every step={
        tikz/.wrap pgfmath arg={
          \draw[red,
                line width = 2.5pt,
                line cap = round] ()--(#1);
      }{name("!b")}
    },
    211,ancestors
    }{}
  },
  [
    [A,
      [B]
      [C]
    ]
    [D
      [E
        [F]
        [G]
        [H]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you are interested in this post: https://np.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/f5q47m/i_wrote_a_python_to_tikz_transpiler_write/fi30w56/

Comment: @HenriMenke I have tried to use for nodewalk.

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Are you interested by a solution outside "forest"?  2) Do you want the colors form the beginning (when you create the graph), or after its creation?

Comment: @DanielN I like the easy way to write tree with forest. I also think that the tree should be logically defined and then decorated. If it is easy for you to produce a none-forest solution, I will be curious to see it.

Comment: Do you want to go just from the root to the node? Or do you want to go from one node to another via the root? The first tree suggests the second, but my reading of the question suggests the first.

Comment: You don't want to just change the colour of the `edge`, but draw the decoration separately?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to do. (Do you want to use nodewalks for the sake of the intellectual exercise or for some practical reason? For example, maybe you want to specify the leaf in the preamble, rather than as an argument in the leaf. If so, the following won't work out-of-the-box, though it could be adapted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\section{Mark all nodes}
\tikzset{
  mark line/.style={
    #1,
    line width = 2.5pt,
    line cap = round,
    shorten >= -1pt, % this (TikZ) key deals with "links" between edges and nodes
  },
}
\forestset{
  mark/.style = {
    mark node=#1,edge={mark line=#1}
  },
  mark node/.style = {
    draw = #1,
    line width = 2pt,
    rounded corners
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree = {
    grow'  = 0,
    l'      = 2.5cm,
    parent anchor=east,
    s sep'  = 1.2cm,
  },
  [
    [A, mark=red
      [B]
      [C,mark=blue]
    ]
    [D, mark=red
      [E, mark=red
        [F]
        [G, mark=red]
        [H]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}


\section{Try to indicate only the leaf}

\forestset{%
  mark me/.style={%
    for nodewalk={while nodewalk valid={parent}{current,fake=parent}}{mark=#1}
  },
}

\begin{forest}
  for tree = {
    grow'  = 0,
    l'      = 2.5cm,
    parent anchor=east,
    s sep'  = 1.2cm,
  },
  [
    [A,
      [B]
      [C]
    ]
    [D
      [E
        [F, mark me=green]
        [G]
        [H]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: two trees, one modified from question]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood correctly your problem...  Using only `tikz`, I suggest the following solution.  There are two styles for the nodes and the edges: `snode` for simple, `cnode` for colored...

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  node distance=1.5cm and 0.2cm,
  snode/.style={rectangle, rounded corners},
  cnode/.style={draw, red, rectangle, rounded corners, line width=1.75pt, text=black},
  sedge/.style={black, thin},
  cedge/.style={red, line width=1.75pt}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (R) {};
  \node[snode, above right=1.5cm and 2cm of R] (A) {A};
  \node[snode, below right=1.5cm and 2cm of R] (D) {D};
  \node[snode, above right=1cm and 2cm of A] (B) {B};
  \node[snode, below right=1cm and 2cm of A] (C) {C};
  \node[snode, right=2cm of D] (E) {E};
  \node[snode, above right=1.3cm and 2cm of E] (F) {F};
  \node[snode, right=2cm of E] (G) {G};
  \node[snode, below right=1.3cm and 2cm of E] (H) {H};

  \path
  (R) edge[sedge] (A) (A.east) edge[sedge] (B)
  (R) edge[sedge] (A) (A.east) edge[sedge] (C)
  (R) edge[sedge] (D) (D.east) edge[sedge] (E) (E.east) edge[sedge] (F) 
  (R) edge[sedge] (D) (D.east) edge[sedge] (E) (E.east) edge[sedge] (G) 
  (R) edge[sedge] (D) (D.east) edge[sedge] (E) (E.east) edge[sedge] (H); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (R) {};
  \node[snode, above right=1.5cm and 2cm of R] (A) {A};
  \node[cnode, below right=1.5cm and 2cm of R] (D) {D};
  \node[snode, above right=1cm and 2cm of A] (B) {B};
  \node[snode, below right=1cm and 2cm of A] (C) {C};
  \node[cnode, right=2cm of D] (E) {E};
  \node[cnode, above right=1.3cm and 2cm of E] (F) {F};
  \node[snode, right=2cm of E] (G) {G};
  \node[snode, below right=1.3cm and 2cm of E] (H) {H};

  \path
  (R) edge[sedge] (A) (A.east) edge[sedge] (B)
  (R) edge[sedge] (A) (A.east) edge[sedge] (C)
  (R) edge[sedge] (D) (D.east) edge[sedge] (E) (E.east) edge[sedge] (G) 
  (R) edge[sedge] (D) (D.east) edge[sedge] (E) (E.east) edge[sedge] (H)
  (R) edge[cedge] (D) (D.east) edge[cedge] (E) (E.east) edge[cedge] (F); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this proposition.